# How to transfer categories (default) to custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, sql

I wanted to move all my posts from the default post type into the new custom post type i've made. I was able to do it using this code:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_type = 'movies' WHERE post_type = 'post'
```

However, i wasn't able to transfer the categories i have on default category.

Is it possible to transfer all the posts including the category into custom post type & custom taxonomoy/category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wp links the posts and the terms in table wp_term_relationships so one doesn't really have to worry about the custom taxonomy. You basically want to change the term ids from that of the default to the term_id of the new term in your custom taxonomy for your select set of posts. Lookup the term_ids and then do

```
UPDATE wp_term_relationships SET  term_taxonomy_id = 'newterm_id' 
WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 'oldterm_id' AND object_id IN 
(SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='movies')
```

Comment: Thank you! Tho, i used a different one. 
`UPDATE wp_term_taxonomy SET taxonomy = 'genres' WHERE taxonomy = 'category'`

Is the way i did it also correct? Or would it cause me any issue?

Comment: Not sure, you've basically renamed the category taxonomy.  So any posts (not just custom post type posts) that used to have category terms will now have the same terms but under a 'genre' not a category.  Are you using normal posts with categories at all ?

Comment: Actually no, you've moved the terms form on etaxonomy to another- should work - you can always add terms back to the original taxonomy.

Comment: Yes. sorry for confusion. That's actually what i wanted. I was trying to move the terms from the default category into the new category (custom taxonomy). Thanks again!